# Add string in a specific part of text file Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, file, insert

At the moment I have a text file looking like this:

```
function NAME(){

}
```

I would like to insert a string in the parenthesis after NAME, I have been researching for hours and have not been able to find a good enough explanation for this problem. Any hep will be gladly appreciated. As extra information I am doing this inside an api so I am using nodejs as well.

I know how to read the file but I am not sure how to then write the string in the correct place. I can overwrite the file if needed as well.

Thanks.

Edit: The Name will change through the different files I have, however the format will not, thus the only thing that would need to be done is add a string to this file inside the first "()".

Edit 2:

```
        var dir = 'operations/';

        fs.readFile(dir+req.params.oid+".js", 'utf8', function (err,data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }

            var res = data.split('(');
            var newStr = res[0] + '(' + req.body.name + res[1];

            fs.writeFile(dir+req.params.oid+".js", newStr, function(err) {
                if (err){
                    throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
                }
                else{
                    console.log("File saved");
                }
            });
        });
```

req.body.name is the string I need added into the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the String part, something like this work :

```
var param = 'myParam';
var str = 'function NAME(){ }';
var res = str.split('(');
var newStr = res[0] + '(' + param + res[1];
// newStr == 'function NAME(myParam){ }'
```

For nodejs, try to look at the 'fs' module to read file and write it (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: Yeah I know how to read and write in nodejs, the problem is knowing how to add the string in the specific location, Ill give your method a try and Ill let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I have added your code with the read and write for nodejs but cant make it work I have update my answer this code, maybe you will spot something I have not.

Comment: So my error is not exactly with the code but with the path itself, Im trying to figure out why it is not finding the file since I use that same path on my code. But as far as I know your solution should work.

Comment: Got it to work thanks, also do you have any idea how I would have to modify the code when adding a second parameter? Because I would need comma between the 1st and 2nd parameter, but not when inputting the first

Comment: There is 1 or 2 parameters or there are always 2 parameters ?

Comment: A solution is :

var res = data.split('(');
var newStr = res[0] + '(' + req.body.name;
if (param2) {
  newStr += ', ' + param2;
}
newStr += res[1];

Comment: Never mind I managed to do it, in case anyone stumbles across this what I did was add a condition to check how many parameters there are in my object and if there is more than 1, then it places it after the parenthesis and adds a comma as well, else it uses your code. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is not the prettiest way to perform this task.
You can try template system as mustacheJs  if you have to do this sort of thing regularly. (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).